# Best way to package resource on an Android app?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, apk

I am an indie mobile app developer. I have a cross-platform game that is currently on iOS and porting to Android.

One of the challenges with Android is that to access resources inside of the APK, it requires a special API rather than just stdio's FILE*. I also have some concern with users modifying my resource files, so I'm not totally convinced of extracting everything from the APK on first boot and storing it in the /files folder on the external storage. Any other developers on here that have encountered this issue? What did you do?

Edit: Just to clarify, I'm not looking for an anti-piracy solution, just an 'anti-mod' solution, so to speak.

Comment: If you're worried about modifications, then sign everything.

Comment: Not sure why you are against using the \assets folder. Files are easy to access and if you want to use unix style file I/O, you can easily copy them from there to the local file system while your app is running.